# Applying Dialog Affect to Inline-Relative Div (without hover affect)

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm trying to place a jquery dialog into a div container relative to another div container. In other words, I'm looking for it to appear in-line and have it's appearance affect the elements surrounding it (eg: if it slides in the div under it is forced to accomodate).

I understand that it ceases to become a traditional dialog, but I'm not sure what else to call it considering I would like to keep the features provided to jQuery's dialog.

What do you think? Any work arounds hacks or solutions?

I would like to avoid setting the position to absolute at all costs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have solved this by now, but here's my solution for posterity:

```
.dialog({
    appendTo: "#placeholderSpan",
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false
})
.parent()
.css({ position: "relative" })
.position({ my: "left top", at: "left top", of: "#placeholderSpan"});
```

I use the new (as of 1.10.0) appendTo property, but it's also possible to append or prepend the dialog on open:

```
.dialog({
    open: function() {
        $(this).parent().prependTo("#placeholderSpan");
    }
});
```

This only worked for me if the position function came at the end, I couldn't use the position function from the dialog options or position the dialog before setting the css position.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qpj3x/2/)